# toggling text color based on other toggled element in page

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a text (#searchLink), when this text is clicked it slides open a -div- (.searchWindow)  using jQuery slidetoggle(). But now i want that text to also change color to match the -div- (example when the -div- opens text should be blue, when closed text should return to white) here is my bugged code which i am struggling with:

```
if ($(".searchWindow").is( ":visible" )){
    $('#searchLink').css("color","blue");
    }
else
   { $('#searchLink').css("color","white");}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: What are you seeing? What is the current result of your script? An `html` snippet may be helpful as well.

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery loaded? Are you pointing to the CDN or loading the files locally?

Comment: what i see..  The slide toggle of the -div- works mainly because a separate code is operating that function. the text (which i want to change color) simply doesn't change color when clicked. Do you believe my code is suppose to work. is there no visible error.

Comment: JQuery is working fine of other pieces of code in the same .js.  and I am loading the file from CDN

Comment: can you provide the html snippet and maybe the function that is making the slide work?

Comment: Is your code shown here even being called when the text is clicked?

Comment: Yes its being called. Are thr other ways to rewrite this code possibly ?

Comment: Heres the code for the working toggle of the -div-     $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchLink").click(function(){
    $(".searchWindow").slideToggle();      
  })  
})

Comment: After doing some tests, I have just noticed the page is responding to my bugged code. I haven't used it the right way that's why i had the problem. I need to alter my code the correct way that's all.  Thanks guys